# Show notification based on a Firebase values

Tags: firebase, flutter, notifications

I want to show notification in my app even if the app is closed.. I don't need Firebase's Push Notification Service. The idea is similar to WhatsApp's message notification service.

When a value is added to firebase by a user another user should receive notification that there is a value change

Can someone tell me how this is done and What should I use to achieve this?

Comment: You receive Firebase Notifications sent from console even if the app is closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push notifications for all major apps run through APNS for iOS, and Firebase Cloud Messaging for Android. While the apps may use a higher-level service from their application code, those services depend on APNS and FCM for the actual message delivery.

To see an example of how to build a notification system on top of this, based on values being written to a database, see [Send Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications for new followers](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications).